# Comment « pour » + « tant » (c-à-d « pourtant ») a-t-il pris le sens de « néanmoins; malgré cela » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [[ Wiktionnaire : ]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pourtant) [Lexicalisation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lexicalisation) de *[pour](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour) [tant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tant)*, du latin *[pro](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro) [tanto](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tanto)*.

Comment: Éléments de réponse à trouver dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pourtant).

Answer (score 1):

Non, car l'expression "séparée" qui a (grosso modo) ce sens est *pour autant*.

Comment: À quelle question réponds-tu ?

Answer (score 0):

The contrast is implied rather than expressed.
Compare the English "You tried hard, and for all that, you did not succeed."